# NodeJS not seeing installed packages?

Tags: node.js

So I'm using the DeathByCaptcha node.js module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deathbycaptcha

I installed it and now it asks me to install the http module

```
Error: Cannot find module 'http'
```

So I installed it using `sudo npm install http`

Then I run `npm -g ls` and see its installed

```
/usr/local/lib
├── http@0.0.0
└─┬ npm@2.15.8
  ├── abbrev@1.0.9
  ├── ansi@0.3.1
  ├── ansi-regex@2.0.0
  ├── ansicolors@0.3.2
  ├── ansistyles@0.1.3
  ├── archy@1.0.0
```

However, I then run my script again and it says no module http installed.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: can you provide some code ?

Comment: I mean its in the first line for the require of the library. var solver = require('2captcha');

Comment: I think there's something wrong, you said that you are using 'deathbycaptcha' module https://www.npmjs.com/package/deathbycaptcha and '2captcha' is another module, btw require works for me for both '2captcha' and 'deathbycaptcha'

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- `deathbycaptcha` was last published three years ago. It is likely to be abandonware and may not work. (Or maybe it will. Just saying...three years is a long time and a lot has changed in Node.js and elsewhere.)
- `http` is a built-in module and you should not need to install anything to use it.
- Do not use `-g` for modules that you wish to `require()`. That is for modules that are command-line tools (like `npm` itself).

Here's a terminal session showing the steps to install `deathbycaptcha` and testing that it can be imported with `require()`.

```
$ node -v
v6.2.2
$ npm -v
3.10.3
$ npm install deathbycaptcha
/Users/trott/projects/deathbycaptchatest
└─┬ deathbycaptcha@0.0.3 
  └─┬ request@2.21.0 
    ├── aws-sign@0.3.0 
    ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0 
    ├── forever-agent@0.5.2 
    ├─┬ form-data@0.0.8 
    │ ├── async@0.2.10 
    │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.7 
    │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5 
    ├─┬ hawk@0.13.1 
    │ ├─┬ boom@0.4.2 
    │ │ └── hoek@0.9.1 
    │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2 
    │ ├── hoek@0.8.5 
    │ └─┬ sntp@0.2.4 
    │   └── hoek@0.9.1 
    ├─┬ http-signature@0.9.11 
    │ ├── asn1@0.1.11 
    │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2 
    │ └── ctype@0.5.2 
    ├── json-stringify-safe@4.0.0 
    ├── mime@1.2.11 
    ├── node-uuid@1.4.7 
    ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0 
    ├── qs@0.6.6 
    └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0 

npm WARN test No description
npm WARN test No repository field.
npm WARN test No README data
npm WARN test No license field.
$
```

Then:

```
$ node
> require('deathbycaptcha');
[Function: DeathByCaptcha]
> LIB-0S8DV17-LT in ~/test
$
```